# Is there any way to get specific range of words?

Tags: python, string, text

```
time='2017-03-29 08:28:55'
```

I hope this str make like below with something. such as split or something

```
new_time='2017-03-29 08:28'
```

How would I do?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried so far. If you haven't, here's a hint: split on `":"` and join the fist two elements.

Comment: Why not just format the time to get what you want in the first place?  Don't split this as a string

Comment: because I used "time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=value)" at first

Comment: and then  2017-03-28 19:32:30.882115+08:00 is the result like this. so that. I did  time=str(time).split('.')[0] . so result is like this.  and I would like to know efficient way

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Thanks for your advice, so my question is just giving using python grammar question. not giving my situation.

Comment: I'm sorry, what?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Split the time on the colon then remove the last element with an array slicing operation. Then rejoin it back together with colons. All one line.

```
new_time = ":".join(time.split(":")[:-1])
```

Comment: Thanks. this is what i want

Comment: @YangJaeLeeUbitus-KR If it worked for you, please accept it as the solution

Answer (score -1):

You can use array slice, try the following code for your example:

```
>>> time='2017-03-29 08:28:55'
>>> time[:-3]
'2017-03-29 08:28'
```

Comment: This is also cool. Thanks!

Comment: @YangJaeLeeUbitus-KR, glad to help.